# Printing percentage sign % in Scilab 6.0.1

Tags: escaping, scilab

I am trying to print two percentage signs to a file using the mfprintf function. My code worked fine in 6.0.0 but after updating to 6.0.1 Scilab crashes without an error.
This is my code:

```
fp = mopen(["test.txt"],'w');
mfprintf(fp,"%% test")
mclose(fp)
```

What i want it to print is `%% test`
Can somebody help? Is this a bug or do I need an escape character? I tried \ but it did nothing.

I found a solution: `mfprintf(fp,"%s test","%%")` still it feels a bit like a hack. If somebody knows a better way I'd still be interested.

Comment: Your solution is not a hack, that's how `mfprintf` should've always work, since it's an interface for "for C-coded version of `fprintf`", as says the help page: you have to use `%s` as placeholder. If I had to guess, the bug was actually escaping the character in previous versions.

Comment: I tried this to get a double quote, but it did not work. I am also on 6.0.1. Escaping with `\"` does not work either in the format, or as a separate string, which is what should work in the C-coded version of fprintf. Something in the interface does not appear to be correct. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed in Scilab 6.0.2